# Как написать правильно код чтобы телеграм бот понимал что ему нужно отправить фото которое отправил юзер мне, в хорошем качества

Tags: python, telebot

мучаюсь с вопросом чтобы бот переотправлял мне фото что отправил юзер боту. Использую pytelegrambotapi и язык python

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['photo'])
def echo_message(message):
    
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chatid, photo=f"вот ваше фото \n{message.from_user.username}")
```

Если сделать некоторые изменения в коде, то он будет переправлять текстовые сообщения, но мне нужно фото. Прошу помощи

Comment: Вытащить фото из сообщения и отправить его, а не пересылать всё сообщение не вариант?